# Alternate secure options for localstorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, local-storage, websecurity

I'm currently developing an application using react.js. When a user logs in the application, I store some user information in the localStorage for some other operations in the application. But as we know the localStorage data can be easily manipulated by the end-user, So I'm looking for an alternate secure way for storing the user information.

Comment: Store the information on the server. Create a session where the data is stored. Give the user a cookie linking them to the session. Lookup data based on the cookie they send you.

Comment: I suppose this depends on how 'sensitive' this data is. Because if it was *really* sensitive, I would avoid storing it client-side.

That said, have you considered signing the data with a key (with a special route in your app), and then storing the data to localStorage? This way, you can know if the data was tampered with. But, for security, the signing would probably be done by the server (via that special route). And at that point, you might as well just store it on the server.

Comment: if the data is sensitive, you'd better not store it in frontEnd, or say store it in localStorage, it's very easy to hack.If it's not so sensitive, you can use some crypto functionalities to crypt it before saved to localStorage, such as `es6-uuid` and some others.

Comment: @fengxh A UUID is not going to protect anything, it's just a unique identifier. Furthermore, if the encryption is done client-side then by definition the client has the data and full control over the encryption process. They can trivially intercept it or reverse it.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks a lot. And I understand what you said. Here I only want to express a shallow protection to store non-sensitive data to client-side, such as localStorage, sessionStorage. If I make some mistakes, sorry here.